# React-datepicker | Calendar not closing on selection of date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker

I've seen this [issue](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/issues/1012#) but it doesn't seem to offer any solution to my problem.

Recently I picked up a project that uses `react-datepicker` and there's an issue where the calendar just isn't closing on selection of a date. Here's a gif showcasing that

[image: reactdatepicker]

My DatePicker component is here

```
const DatePicker: FC<Props> = ({
  label,
  icon,
  date,
  onChange,
  minDate,
  maxDate,
  selectsStart,
  selectsEnd,
}) => {
  const dateObj = useMemo(() => (date ? date.toDate() : null), [date])
  const minDateObj = useMemo(() => (minDate ? minDate.toDate() : null), [
    minDate,
  ])
  const maxDateObj = useMemo(() => (maxDate ? maxDate.toDate() : null), [
    maxDate,
  ])

  return (
    <div className={css.host}>
      <div className={css.label}>{label}</div>
      <label className={`${css.wrapper}`}>
        {icon}
        <ReactDatePicker
          selected={dateObj}
          className={css.input}
          calendarClassName={css.calendar}
          showTimeSelect
          dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy h:mm aa"
          onChange={(newDate: Date, e) => {
            if (newDate) {
              const momentDate = moment(newDate)
              onChange(momentDate)
            }
          }}
          startDate={minDateObj}
          endDate={maxDateObj}
          minDate={minDateObj}
          maxDate={maxDateObj}
          selectsStart={selectsStart}
          selectsEnd={selectsEnd}
          showPopperArrow={false}
          popperModifiers={{
            offset: {
              enabled: true,
              offset: '-28px, 4px',
            },
          }}
          renderCustomHeader={customHeader}
        />
      </label>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And it's being used here

```
<div
      className={css.host}
      onKeyUp={(evt) => {
        if (evt.keyCode === 13) {
          onSearch({ startDate, endDate, text })
        }
      }}
    >
      <DatePicker
        id="startDate"
        label="Start date"
        icon={<DateStartIcon width={16} height={16} />}
        date={startDate}
        maxDate={endDate}
        onChange={(newDate: Moment) => {
          setStartDate(newDate)
        }}
        selectsStart
      />
</div>
```

Inside my `ReactDatePicker` I tried to set the `onChange` like so

```
onChange={(newDate: Date, e) => {
    if (newDate) {
        if (e && typeof e.preventDefault === 'function') {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        const momentDate = moment(newDate)
        onChange(momentDate)
    }
}}
```

I'm not sure what else I can do here so any help would be great!

Comment: https://reactdatepicker.com/ datepicker in their page is working as you want right?

Comment: Yes, @Kalhan.Toress, I also wondered if it was a problem related with my browser but it's working there

Comment: https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/issues/1012
move label tag or cover div tag

Answer (score 3):

This issue occurs because you are wrapping you datepicker component inside a `<label>` tag, unwrap the datepicker from it like this:

```js
const DatePicker: FC<Props> = ({
  label,
  icon,
  date,
  onChange,
  minDate,
  maxDate,
  selectsStart,
  selectsEnd,
}) => {
  const dateObj = useMemo(() => (date ? date.toDate() : null), [date])
  const minDateObj = useMemo(() => (minDate ? minDate.toDate() : null), [
    minDate,
  ])
  const maxDateObj = useMemo(() => (maxDate ? maxDate.toDate() : null), [
    maxDate,
  ])

  return (
    <div className={css.host}>
      <div className={css.label}>{label}</div>
      <label className={`${css.wrapper}`}>
        {icon}
      </label>
        
      <ReactDatePicker
        selected={dateObj}
        className={css.input}
        calendarClassName={css.calendar}
        showTimeSelect
        dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy h:mm aa"
        onChange={(newDate: Date, e) => {
          if (newDate) {
            const momentDate = moment(newDate)
            onChange(momentDate)
          }
        }}
        startDate={minDateObj}
        endDate={maxDateObj}
        minDate={minDateObj}
        maxDate={maxDateObj}
        selectsStart={selectsStart}
        selectsEnd={selectsEnd}
        showPopperArrow={false}
        popperModifiers={{
          offset: {
            enabled: true,
            offset: '-28px, 4px',
          },
        }}
        renderCustomHeader={customHeader}
      />
      
    </div>
  )
}
```

You'll likely need to redo some CSS

Comment: nice catch, this indeed was issue in my case - moving the DP outside of the label tag solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Use shouldCloseOnSelect prop as true to forcefully close after selection

```
 () => {
      const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
      return (
        <DatePicker
          selected={startDate}
          onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}
          shouldCloseOnSelect={true}
        />
      );
    };
```

**Update**
You are using `showTimeSelect` property which awaits selection of time and then upon selection closes it automatically. This is the designed feature of React Datepicker. If you want to just select date and keep the same time and close upon selection of date then you can use another variant from datepicker which is input time.

```
() => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  return (
    <DatePicker
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}
      timeInputLabel="Time:"
      dateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy h:mm aa"
      showTimeInput
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: I've tried this but using `shouldCloseOnSelect={true}` doesn't solve my problem